# Creating Data Extensions by running queries

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sqlserver

Is it possible to create data extensions by running a query with the CREATE TABLE function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Query Activities can only be `Select` statements.

Here is what's supported:

> The SQL support for the Query Activity is based on SQL Server 2005
>   capabilities.
>
> Only SELECT statements to data extension or data views in an account
>   or in the parent account
>
> - Nested Queries
> - UNION
> - JOIN
> - GROUP BY
>
> Conditional Statements
>
> - IF Constructs
> - CASE Statements
>
> Functions
>
> - Most functions (i.e. MIN, MAX, etc) are supported
> - CAST and CONVERT
>
> Unsupported elements
>
> - Variables
> - Cursors
> - User Defined Functions
> - Transaction and Locking
> - GOTO
> - PRINT
> - Any sp_* stored procedure
> - EXEC
> - Temporary Tables and Common Table Expressions
> - TEXT and IMAGE Functions

**Reference**

- [**Query Activity: SQL Support**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/#section_6)

Comment: This isnt the first time you have come to the rescue @Adam Spriggs. Thanks